# Probable syntax-error in multi-monitor-, GUI- and clipboard-context

Tags: autohotkey

I'm new to AHK and the following syntax doesn't work:

`%Final_x% -= (%width% / 2)`

Can you spot my error?

Comment: Why are you using something like %xxx% on the left side of an assignment statement? It would normally just be xxx.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Probable syntax-error in multi-monitor-, GUI- & clipboard-context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75356145/probable-syntax-error-in-multi-monitor-gui-clipboard-context)

Comment: Please don't post the same question multiple times

Comment: @James Z This was a mistake, I have deleted the duplicate in the meantime. Can you also spot the error in my code?

Comment: @paxdiablo I've tried with and without  %% on the left side, nothing worked, but over that code line %Final_x% and %width% still hold meaningful pixel values, so the error must happen in said code line below. Surely it's just a stupid newbie mistake. Can you fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the doc on AHK's somewhat quirky varibale syntax I managed to fix it this way:

`Final_x := Final_x - width / 2`

Thank you all for your contributions!

Comment: Hey, your shorthand method can also work. Try: `Final_x -= width/2`. If you don't like AutoHotkey's quirky syntax, try [v2](https://www.autohotkey.com/v2/), which is more predictable.